# How to convert a complex string to dict of dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string with complex dict. I want to convert that as dict of dict recursively

eg:
`s = "{'key1':\"{'status': 'completed','media': {'key2':{'value1': False, 'key3': False},'key4':{'active': True}\"}"`

As I am new to python, I couldnt crack this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in the string, take a look at the json library:

```
import json
s = "{'key1':\"{'status': 'completed','media': {'key2':{'value1': False, 'key3': False},'key4':{'active': True}\"}"
imported_dict = json.loads(s)
```

Then, you can use `imported_dict` to re-form to your new dictionary format.